# Converting Byte Array To Image Throws "Parameter is not valid."

Tags: c#, arrays, varbinary

I'm trying to convert several byte arrays (stored in SQL Server 2008 R2 as varbinary(8000)) into images so I can attach them to a PDF file (an example of the data is below). I keep getting "Parameter is not valid." when creating the Image from the MemoryStream. Any help on this?

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
Image image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
```

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

Comment: Sounds like the byte array isn't a valid image.

Comment: What is the image format? It does not look like any common image format the Image class would understand.

Comment: I'm unaware of the image format, but I know that the result should be one of many logos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a

```
% file output 
output: PCX ver. 2.8 image data, with palette
```

under linux I just transformed your hex stream from plain text to a binary file called `output`

> echo
>   "0A020101000000005E006500FA00FA0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010C00010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000C1C0C7000FC2FFC1FE80C70007C2FFC1FE1FC7FFC1F03FC1FFC1FE3FC7FFC1F807C1FFC1FE3FC8FFC1F3C1FFC1FE3FC8FFC1FEC1FFC1FE3FC8FFC1FE7FC1FE3FC9FFBFC1FE3FC9FFC1DFC1FE3FC9FFC1CFC1FE3FC9FFC1F3C1FE3FC9FFC1FBC1FE3FC9FFC1F9C1FE3FC9FFC1F9C1FE3FC9FFC1FCC1FE3FC9FFC1FE7E3FC9FFC1FE7E3FCAFF7E3FC2FFC1FCC20007C4FF3E3FC2FFC1F8C300C4FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C2FFC1FC7FC3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C2FFC1FC3FC3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C3FF9FC3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1CFC3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1E7C3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F3C3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F3C3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F3C3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F3C3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F3C3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F3C3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F3C2FFC1FE7E3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1E7C2FFC1FE7E3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1C7C2FFC1FCC1FE3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1C7C2FFC1F9C1FE3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1DFC2FFC1F9C1FE3FC2FFC1F1C3FFBFC2FFC1F9C1FE3FC2FFC1F1C2FFC1FC3FC2FFC1F3C1FE3FC2FFC1F0C2FFC1F8C3FFC1E7C1FE3FC2FFC1FEC2000FC3FFC1CFC1FE3FC3FFC2000FC3FF9FC1FE3FC9FF3FC1FE3FC8FFC1FE7FC1FE3FC8FFC1F0C1FFC1FE3FC8FFC1E7C1FFC1FE3FC8FFC1CFC1FFC1FE3FC8FF8FC1FFC1FE3FC8FFC1E0C1FFC1FE3FC8FFC1F8C1FFC1FE3FC8FFC1FC1FC1FE3FC9FF8FC1FE3FC9FFC1E7C1FE3FC9FFC1F0C1FE3FC9FFC1FE7E3FCAFF7E3FC2FFC1FCC300C4FF3E3FC2FFC1F8C3001FC3FF3E3FC2FFC1F1C3FF8FC3FF9E3FC2FFC1F1C3FF87C3FFC1CE3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F3C3FFC1CE3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F9C3FFC1EE3FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1FCC3FFC1E43FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1FE7FC2FFC1E43FC2FFC1F1C4FF3FC2FFC1E43FC2FFC1F1C4FF1FC2FFC1F03FC2FFC1F1C4FF1FC2FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C4FF1FC2FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C4FF1FC2FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C4FF1FC2FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C4FF1FC2FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C4FF1FC2FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C4FF1FC2FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1FE7FC2FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1FEC3FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F9C3FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F3C3FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C3FFC1F7C3FFC1F83FC2FFC1F1C2FFC1FE0FC3FFC1F83FC2FFC1F0C3003FC3FFC1F83FC2FFC1F8C20001C4FFC1F83FC2FFC1FCC20003C4FFC1FC3FCAFFC1E43FCAFFC1E43FCAFFC1E43FCAFFC1EE3FCAFFC1EE3FCAFFC1CE3FCAFF3E3FCAFF7E3FC9FFC1FE7E3FC9FFC1FE7E3FC9FFC1FCC1FE3FC9FFC1F1C1FE3FC9FFC1C3C1FE3FC9FFC1DFC1FE3FC9FF9FC1FE3FC8FFC1E07FC1FE3FC8FFC1C1C1FFC1FE1FC7FF001FC1FFC1FEC9003FC1FFC1FE80C700C3FFC1FEC1C0C700C3FFC1FE"
>   | xxd -p -r >output

and then the easy part with `file output` to get the name of the file format from the utility `file`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Knowing that the hex stream was a PCX image I used Magick.NET to convert the byte array to a bmp and insert the bmp on the PDF document. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you know the encoding, as the Image.FromStream method knows only a limited number of formats.

Make sure that the Position of your MemoryStream is set properly to 0, and not to the end - otherwise, any reads will begin at the end appear to be empty, instead of starting at the beginning.

Also, note that

> This constructor does not expose the underlying stream. GetBuffer throws UnauthorizedAccessException.[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Thus, this could be caused by some of the way Bitmap is handling the underlying stream. IF need be, try making an empty memorystream, copying the byte into it, and then resetting the position

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
foreach(var b in byteArray) memoryStream.WriteByte(b);
memoryStream.Position = 0;
Image image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
```

Comment: Any ideas as to what I can do if I have no way of telling what format the data has been encoded as?

Answer (score 0):

The byte array you gave is 1117 bytes long. That's not evenly divisible by 4 or 3, so I'm pretty certain that the image is not raw bytes and is actually encoded in an image format of some sort.

The Image.FromStream() method can't decode an encoded image without knowing the format, and the byte array you gave doesn't specify what that format is. Therefore the parameter you gave is invalid. If you know the format of the image you could attempt to insert a header into the byte array before the rest of the image, and see if that helps. It's curious you have the image but not its header, although it doesn't appear to be a base-64 string either.

Without knowing the image format it could be difficult to convert these byte arrays into images. Is there any way you could find out what they are? How is the image data retrieved to be stored?

Comment: No, there's no way we can find out what the images are. I don't really need to store the data retrieved after converting it, I just need to draw the image/logo on a ticket (which is a PDFSharp doc).